# How to create a multiple display from .NET web application?

Tags: javascript, c#

Hi I'm developing a web application for my company. I'm not really sure whether ASP.NET web application can support to display out the display for 4 different HTML ports which installed into the CPU.

Basically the .NET application is running on web but I need idea on how to configure each image to specific HDMI port which installed in the CPU itself.

Comment: A web application runs in a browser. If your web application makes my browser do weird things like open new browser instances on different screens, I start screaming for my anti-virus program. It's as scary as opening a Word document and having 4 Word instances on four screen all of a sudden.

Comment: Don't misunderstand the purpose of desktop & web apps - they're using different principles. Web apps tends to run in browser windows/tabs - single window/tab is enough (optimized for minimal resources).

Comment: Yea. it running on a browser base. I'm not sure whether it can be develop by splitting screen like how you project your screen on the projector.

Comment: "4 different HTML ports which installed into the CPU" - what is this I don't even. Are you able to use 4 different HDMI ports simultaneously, i.e. by expanding your Windows desktop over them? In that case you can do pretty much anything: either **A)** open 4 different browsers, one on each screen, or **B)** create a .NET desktop app with 4 different windows, one on each screen.

Comment: I have a CPU which have 4 HDMI ports. We are developing an advertisement application which allow one program to control the content in 4 different screens which is connected to the CPU.